# Cohort analysis – Data retrieval task ()

Tags: sql, postgresql

Cohort – Customers who registered in one week (e.g. week 19, ) or month (e.g. July)

Generate initial date from users_users table

Create SQL for

- Weekly logins
- Weekly operations

What I need to do is to create some kind of table, which would include user logins weekly.

[image]

Our tables:

user login logs:

[image]

user table

[image]

How would I be able to do it? I'm stuck here for a few days, tried re-searching a lot, but still didn't really find a good solution.

Comment: and where did you stuck? What is unclear for you?

Comment: How would I be able to do it? I'm green at SQL

Comment: Please provide table definitions (ddl) and sample input data, as text - **[no images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)**, or create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). Also explain what the columns in your output mean. Ie Week14, week0=10, week1=5,... what do those numbers actually mean?

Comment: What defines a week and the what constitutes a week number. (ISO definition?, something else?).  Each cohort has weeks0-week6 does that mean looking at a 7 week period, or is it actually an open ended number of weeks terminating with current week? Then you say "generate initial date from users_users table" does this mean each user starts on a different week? Not to mention monthly!

Comment: @Belayer we have to get each week user login count in the first week and then see how many of them logged in at other week

Comment: Without input data still makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing exactly what fields the cohort and the calculation should be based on makes the whole exercise a bit complex. If we assume the Cohort in your 1st column is based on `date_joined` of `users_user` you can find at which cohort a particular user belongs to with:

```
to_char(date_joined,'IYYY-IW')
```

If then thw `Week 0` -> `Week 6` columns depend on how long it took from `date_joined` to `last_login` (if not I believe you can manage to substitute the relevant columns) you can achieve such difference in days with

```
(last_login - date_joined)
```

If you divide by `7` and take the `floor`, you should end up calculating correctly what you're looking for.

An example is the following, recreating the table `users_user` and populating it  with

```
create table users_user 
(
id serial,
username varchar,
last_login date,
date_joined date
);

insert into users_user (username, last_login, date_joined) values ('Carlo', '2021-05-15', '2021-05-10');
insert into users_user (username, last_login, date_joined) values ('Ugo', '2021-05-31', '2021-05-20');
insert into users_user (username, last_login, date_joined) values ('Gino', '2021-05-30', '2021-05-01');
insert into users_user (username, last_login, date_joined) values ('Pino', '2021-05-05', '2021-05-05');
insert into users_user (username, last_login, date_joined) values ('Sandra', '2021-05-31', '2021-05-31');
```

the following query returns cohorts and windows

```
defaultdb=> select to_char(date_joined,'IYYY-IW') week_cohort, floor((last_login - date_joined)/7) week_window, id, username from users_user;
 week_cohort | week_window | id | username 
-------------+-------------+----+----------
 2021-19     |           0 |  1 | Carlo
 2021-20     |           1 |  2 | Ugo
 2021-17     |           4 |  3 | Gino
 2021-18     |           0 |  4 | Pino
 2021-22     |           0 |  5 | Sandra
(5 rows)
```

Comment: My fields were date, your fields seem to be `timestamp`. If that's the case you can achieve the same with `DATE_PART('day',(last_login - date_joined))`

Comment: What does week_window stand for? It's a nice solution, but as you can see I need triangle stats.